# Parse JSON to android application

Tags: android, json, parsing

That's my JSON and I must parse it and show it in the application

```
{
"idUsuario":20,
"nomeUsuario":"Barbara Trzaskos",
"CPF":"978824029-15",
"email":"barbaratrzaskos@ufpr.br",
"sigla":"BTR",
"senha":"safira",
"instuicao":"Universidade Federal do Paraná",
"listaDePontos":[
{
"idPonto":"BTR0001",
"pontoNome":"BTR-0001",
"dtCampo":"2011-04-29T00:00:00",
"projeto":2,
"UTMEste":547276.0,
"UTMNorte":7285137.0,
"UTMFuso":22,
"UTMHemisferio":"S",
"latDec":-24.5469,
"longDec":-50.5332,
"altitude":0,
"descPonto":"Arenito mal selecionado. Apresenta fina banda de deformação, como um suave ressalto no relevo e coloração mais clara. Exibe plano subvertical com padrão anastomosado e cinemática aparente sinistral",
"complement":"Coleta de amostra orientada.",
"analiseCampo":{
"nomeEstrutura":"-",
"idAnCampo":"BTR0001",
"descEstrutura":"",
"ehBrunton":true,
"analiseEstruturais":[
{
"idEstrutura":"BTR0001001",
"ordem":0,
"tipo":"Plano",
"codigo":"F",
"brunton":"N42W/86SW",
"clar":"228/86",
"azimute":"228",
"direcao":"42",
"quadrante":"SW",
"sentido":"Sinistral",
"descricao":"",
"mergulho":"86",
"familia":""
}
]
},
"arquivos":[
],
"idUnigadeGeologica":[
{
"idUnidade":816
},
{
"idUnidade":2295
}
]
}
]
}
```

How can I compile it? Cause this have array inside array and other things and I don't know how to do it. Sorry about the code be in portuguese but I didn't had time to translate.

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: If you want to parse JSON, if I am understanding correctly, then you can use any of the JSON libraries, like gson from Google..

Comment: You can read more about JSON for android [in this blog post](http://echofriendlyapp.tumblr.com/post/46382053642/understanding-json-for-android). It explains how to unnest different JSON components to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First construct a JSON object with your JSON string:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
```

Then you can get a field from it using

```
jObject.getString("nomeUsuario");
```

If you want to get an array use

```
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("listaDePontos"));
```

and then iterate through the array in this manner

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject temp = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
    //get everything from 'temp' here just like above

}
```